# ImageMagick adding white background while converting .ai file to png

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am using image magick library to convert .ai file into .png but the problem is that it is adding extra white background in the image.

I have tried using this code

```
$image = new Imagick();
            $image->readimage($imagePath);
            $image->setImageFormat('png');
            $image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
            $image->trimImage(0);
            $image->writeImage($saveImagePath);
```

it returns the image with unwanted white background, attaching the result image
[image]

and here is the original ai file which has no background at all

https://ufile.io/k3cs98ky

Comment: Post the original AI file

Comment: @fmw42 i added original file link in the post, any help will be appreciated

Comment: It works fine in command line `convert borsten.ai -trim +repage x.png` using IM 6.9.12.22 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra using [ghostscript library 9.54]. Perhaps it is your version of Ghostscript or your version of ImageMagick. Did you try leaving off ` $image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));` or put it before reading the input.

Comment: @fmw42 i tiried this command "convert -background none -size 1024x1024 $imagePath $saveImagePath" and it si working, thanks for the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used command line script to convert .ai file to .png and this is the more accurate result

this is the command i used

```
convert -background none -size 1024x1024 $imagePath $saveImagePath
```